# Jaxb marshelling expected xsi:nil="true" in the element when the value is decimal which will be null, but xsi:nil="true" is not coming

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

The below code is generating the xml given below with out `xsi:nil=true`, why it is not generating that attribute?

XML out from the below demo code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <Market>
      <detail>
          <shipping available="false"/>
       </detail>
   </Market>
```

Jaxb class used to generate the xml output from marshelling, i have also added the `@XmlElement(nillable = true)` annotation. it is not outputing the `xsi:nil=true` in the xml:

```
package com.jverstry.annotations.generics;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "detail"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Market")
public class Market {

    @XmlElement(required = false)
    protected Detail detail;

    public Detail getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(Detail detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "shipping"})
    public static class Detail {

        @XmlElementRef(name="shipping")
        protected JAXBElement<Shipping> shipping;

        public JAXBElement<Shipping> getShipping() {
            return shipping;
        }

        public void setShipping(JAXBElement<Shipping> value) {
            this.shipping = value;
        }


        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
        public static class Shipping {

            @XmlValue
            protected BigDecimal value;

            @XmlAttribute(name = "available")
            protected Boolean available;

            public BigDecimal getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(BigDecimal value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            public Boolean getAvailable() {
                return available;
            }

            public void setAvailable(Boolean value) {
                this.available = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ObjectFactory class:

```
package com.jverstry.annotations.generics;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "shipping")
    public JAXBElement<Market.Detail.Shipping> createShipping(Market.Detail.Shipping value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Market.Detail.Shipping>(new QName("shipping"), Market.Detail.Shipping.class, value);
    }
}
```

Running jaxb class for getting xml:

```
package com.jverstry.annotations.generics;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Market.class,ObjectFactory.class);

        Market market = new Market();  
        Market.Detail md = new Market.Detail();

        Market.Detail.Shipping mds = new  Market.Detail.Shipping();
        mds.setAvailable(false);
        JAXBElement<Market.Detail.Shipping> shipping = new ObjectFactory().createShipping(mds);

        md.setShipping(shipping);
        market.setDetail(md);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(market, System.out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The presence of `xsi:nil="true"` would denote a `Market.Detail` object whose `shipping` property is `null`.  This isn't the case here - you've got a non-null `Market.Detail.Shipping` object with an empty value.  In order to allow `xsi:nil` in combination with other attributes you'd have to declare the `shipping` property as a `JAXBElement<Shipping>` instead of just `Shipping`:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "shipping"})
    public static class Detail
    {

        @XmlElement(nillable = true)
        protected JAXBElement<Market.Detail.Shipping> shipping;

        public JAXBElement<Market.Detail.Shipping> getShipping() {
            return shipping;
        }

        public void setShipping(JAXBElement<Market.Detail.Shipping> value) {
            this.shipping= value;
        }


        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
        public static class Shipping
        {
            // as before
        }
    }
```

and now `<shipping available="false" xsi:nil="true"/>` would be represented by a `JAXBElement` whose `isNil()` returns `true` and whose `getValue()` is a non-null instance of `Shipping` whose `getAvailable()` returns `false`.

---

Following your latest edit to the question - now you have the infrastructure to create `JAXBElement<Shipping>` instances you simply need to set the `nil` property as required:

```
    Market.Detail.Shipping mds = new  Market.Detail.Shipping();
    mds.setAvailable(false);
    JAXBElement<Market.Detail.Shipping> shipping = new ObjectFactory().createShipping(mds);
    shipping.setNil(true); // mark the element as nil

    md.setShipping(shipping);
```